# How to compare dates when DST is changing with Laravel / Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, dst, php-carbon

I have a collection of objects with a field time with a timestep of 30min:

I am scanning my list for data holes, meaning in this list, it should return :

```
dataHoleStart:    2020-03-29 04:30
dataHoleEnd  :    2020-03-29 08:30
```

Thing is I get an issue the 29 of this year, because it is the day we change DST.

```
There is no hole:2020-03-29 01:00
There is no hole:2020-03-29 01:30
There is no hole:2020-03-29 03:00
There is no hole:2020-03-29 03:30
New hole: 2020-03-29 03:00
Existing hole: 2020-03-29 03:30
Existing hole: 2020-03-29 04:00
Existing hole: 2020-03-29 04:30
Existing hole: 2020-03-29 05:00
```

But checking into my Postgres Database, I can see data is quite regular, there is no hole.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($measures as $key => $measure) {
            if ($key == 0) continue;
            $nextTS = (clone $ts_cursor)->addMinutes(30);
            if ($measure->time->eq($nextTS)) {
                $ts_cursor = $nextTS;
                echo "There is no hole:". $measure->time->format('yy-m-d H:i'). "<br/>";
                continue;
            }
            // Here we have a hole.
            if ($missingDataIni != null) {
                // We are in an existing hole
                $ts_cursor = $nextTS;
                echo('Existing hole: ' .$measure->time->format('yy-m-d H:i'). "<br/>");
            } else {
                // We create a new hole
                $missingDataIni = $nextTS;
                $ts_cursor = $nextTS;
                echo 'New hole: '.$measure->time->format('yy-m-d H:i'). "<br/>";
            }

        }
```

I tried to convert Carbon fields to timestamp, but I still have the same problem.

Also, in `config/app.php`, I have my timezone defined to:

```
'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',
```

How should I handle date comparison including DST with `Carbon` ?

Comment: The fact is working with `'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris',` in your `config/app.php` is a bad idea. See https://medium.com/@kylekatarnls/always-use-utc-dates-and-times-8a8200ca3164 Europe/Paris should come when you want to format or handle dates in the particular context of a user. Else handle time in an agnostic way using UTC.

Comment: The main problem when you record DST-timezone date-times in your DB is: when string 25 oct 2020 02h30 (for Paris timezone), you don't know if it's 2h30 winter time or summer time. So you should have UTC (GMT) timezone for you DB and your Laravel config so it's aligned, then if you need to display a date at Paris time, it's easy to `->tz('Europe/Paris')` on a Carbon instance.

Comment: I agree with you about not working in UTC. For the record, all my DB dates are in UTC. But to manage DST, I must work work with timezone, otherwise, I couldn't  get the transitions, that are timezone dependents

Comment: oooh, you were right, I ended up changing the timezone to UTC

Answer (score 0):

I solve it using `getTransitions`

Here is the code:

```
// We get the transition at timezone.
$transitions = collect($tz->getTransitions($start->format('U'), $end->format('U')))
    ->map(function ($transition) use ($tz) {
        return (new Carbon($transition['time']))->timezone($tz)->toAtomString();
    })->toArray();

foreach ($measures as $key => $measure) {
    if ($key == 0) continue;
    $nextTS = (clone $ts_cursor)->addMinutes(30);
    if ($measure->time->timezone($tz)->eq($nextTS)) {
        $ts_cursor = $nextTS;
        echo "There is no hole:" . $measure->time->timezone($tz)->toAtomString() . "<br/>";
        continue;
    }
    if (in_array($measure->time->timezone($tz)->toAtomString(), $transitions)) {
        echo "Transition setting ts_cursor:".$ts_cursor->timezone($tz)->toAtomString(). "<br/>";
        $ts_cursor = $ts_cursor->addMinutes(-30);
        continue;
    }

    // Here we have a hole.
    if ($missingDataIni != null) {
        // We are in an existing hole
        echo('Existing hole: ' . $measure->time->timezone($tz)->toAtomString() . "<br/>");
        $ts_cursor = $nextTS;
    } else {
        // We create a new hole
        $ts_cursor = $nextTS;
        $missingDataIni = $ts_cursor;
        echo 'New hole: ' . $ts_cursor->timezone($tz)->toAtomString() . "<br/>";
    }
}
```